# What happens when you connect a 16bit analog device to a 10bit adc

Tags: arduino, adc

Can someone explain  what happens when you hook up a 16bit analog device to a 10bit ADC (like the one on the Arduino).Will it still function?Will the 10bit ADC normalize the values with a lower resolution?

Also how would i go by interfacing 16bit analog device to the Arduino.

thanks in advance.

[link to the device im looking at. measuring frequency is at 2kHz](https://www.mysick.com/eCat.aspx?go=DataSheet&Cat=Row&At=Fa&Cult=English&ProductID=40620)

Comment: need more details on that 16 bit analog device.. especially the frequency of your measurement. Some oversampling may be your ally.

Comment: There's no such thing as a 16-bit analog device

Answer (score 11):

You mean an analogue device with 16-bit equivalent SNR/resolution? (analogue doesn't have  discrete steps) It will simply be sampled at 10-bit resolution by the ADC.

However, you can use techniques like oversampling, averaging and dithering to increase the resolution to more bits. Very roughly, say we have a one bit ADC with a step of 1V, and you have a signal that is at 0.5V - the ADC will report 1 half the time and 0 half the time (noise will make sure of this). If we take lots of samples and average them (add them all up and divide by number of samples) we will get around 0.5. The more samples we take the more accurate this will be, the downside is the highest frequency we can see goes down, as we are in effect creating a (digital) low pass filter.

So yes, it will still function. Sorry I can't help with the exact details of interfacing as I have never used an Arduino, although it will be a case of "input signal to ADC pin".

Answer (score 6):

16-bit analog is a *contradictio in terminis*. It's either discrete, like 16-bit, for 65 536 discrete levels, or it's continuous, or analog.

16-bit digital has \$2^{16}\$ or 65 536 discrete levels, 10-bit has \$2^{10}\$ or 1024 discrete levels. So, if you use the same reference for your ADC, for every step in your 10-bit ADC you have 64 smaller steps in the 16-bit source. So as long as the variations in your source signal remain smaller than 64 steps (the lower 6 bits) you won't see a variation in the 10-bit sampled signal. That's the consequence of the lower resolution. But even then a smoothed 1-bit signal will pretty closely resemble a smoothed 16-bit signal.

Answer (score 2):

What they said. Plus -

An ADC is blissfully unaware of the "accuracy" of its input signal. it dos not "know" how it was made or how close you expect it to be to some value.

The ADC just does its job in splendoured isolation. It it's a 10 bit ADC then it will try to measure the input signal with an accuracy of  1/2^10th = 1 part on 1024 of its reference voltage.

**Affects of input variations:** Input signal characteristics may affect the result. A signal that varies rapidly or has substantial noise on it may make it impossible for the ADC to return an accurate value - there may **not be** and accurate value due to the variations. A DC level produced by a device with 1 part in 2^16 accuracy will ideally not have vast amounts of noise on it (or why bother having such accuracy) but the smooth noise free signal will be easier for the ADC to measure to 1 part in 1024 (= 2^10).

**Accuracy & Resolution:** Note that I used the term "accuracy" above. This is somewhat more complex than it may at first seem. Devices may have a part in 1024 accuracy but not resolution. Or may have high resolution but lower accuracy. Then there's linearity ... ;-). BUT for now the "sloppy" terminology of "accuracy" is wel enough understood for this purpose.